# c++ double rounding problems

Tags: c++

Why?

```
11979999 / 10000 = 1197.999877930
```

With

```
printf("%f\n", static_cast<double>(((float)11979999 / (float)10000)));
```

Instead of

```
1197.9999
```

And how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you did the calculation in single precision, then you converted the result to double. If you want double precision, do the calculation in double precision:

```
  printf("%f\n", (double)11979999 / (double)10000);
```

Comment: perfect!
1197.999900 is the output now.